# How to do dynamic filtering or client side filtering of a table as text is typed in a textbox

Tags: angular

[image: screenshot of my partially completed assignment]i need to complete an assignment. the assignment should use client-side filtering of data as text is entered in text-box. how to implement it. Below is the problem statement of assignment

The problem statement is:
Banks Search Application

You need to develop a single page web app (preferably, but not necessarily in AngularJS). 
The app should list and search for banks that are fetched from the API mentioned below. There should be a dropdown for cities (just put in 5 cities in there) and there is a search bar. As I type in the search area, the table should be dynamically filtered (client-side filtering). Search should be across all fields.

Here's the backend API to get a list of banks: https://vast-shore-74260.herokuapp.com/banks?city=MUMBAI

Essentials your applications should have: 
bank search screen which would show a list of banks
user should be able to search by text for the banks, across all the fields (important: there would be no search button)

I tried using filters as desctibed in this url:https://codeburst.io/create-a-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-with-angular-4-21fd3a5bec5c

but this cant be implemented on a bootstrap table

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BankhttpService } from '../bankhttp.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   public searchString: string;  
   public nativeBranch;

   constructor(public bankHttpService : BankhttpService) {
      console.log('Home component constructor is called');
   }


   ngOnInit() {
      console.log('Home component onIniti called');

      this.bankHttpService.getBankBranches().subscribe(
         data=>{
            console.log('logging data');
            console.log(data);
            this.nativeBranch = data;
            console.log(this.nativeBranch)
         },
         error=>{
            console.log('Some error occured');
            console.log(error.errorMessage);
         }
      )
   }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <br>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchString" placeholder="Type to search..."
              [(ngModel)]="searchString" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col">

      <div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table  table-striped css-serial">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Sl.No.</th>
              <th scope="col">City</th>
              <th scope="col">Bank Name</th>
              <th scope="col">IFSC</th>
              <th scope="col">Branch</th>
              <th class="w-15" scope="col">Bank ID</th>
              <th scope="col">District</th>
              <th scope="col">State</th>
              <th class="w-15" scope="col">Address</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr style="align-self: center" *ngFor="let native of nativeBranch | filter : 'name' : 
searchString; let i = index">
              <td> </td>
              <td>{{native.city}}</td>
              <td>{{native.bank_name}}</td>
              <td>{{native.ifsc}}</td>
              <td>{{native.branch}}</td>
              <td>{{native.bank_id}}</td>
              <td>{{native.district}}</td>
              <td>{{native.state}}</td>
              <td>{{native.address}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**sharedmodule that is servicecomponent** 
**bankhttpservice**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BankhttpService {
  private baseUrl = "https://vast-shore-74260.herokuapp.com/banks";
  public myCity = "MUMBAI"

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Bank http service called');
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log('Handle http error');
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }


  public getBankBranches(): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '?city=' +
      this.myCity);
    console.log(myResponse);
    return myResponse;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this is a pretty classic observable use case....

first, turn your search string into a form control:

```
public searchString: FormControl<string> = new FormControl('');  

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchString" placeholder="Type to search..."
              [formControl]="searchString" />
```

next, turn that nativeBranch into an observable and use the async pipe, and get rid of that performance hazard filter pipe:

```
public nativeBranch$: Observable<any[]>;

this.nativeBranch$ = this.bankHttpService.getBankBranches();

<tr style="align-self: center" *ngFor="let native of nativeBranch$ | async; let i = index">
```

finally, combine your form control valueChanges observable and your nativeBranch$ observable to filter your results:

```
const searchString$ = this.searchString.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''), // start it off
  debounceTime(300), // debounce the user input
  distinctUntilChanged() // only emit when it actually changes
);
this.nativeBranch$ = combineLatest(this.bankHttpService.getBankBranches(), 
                                   searchString$).pipe(
  map(([branches, searchString]) => {
    if (searchString) {
      return branches.filter(b => b.name.includes(searchString)); // whatever your filter logic is
    }
    return branches;
  })
);
```

now you have a high performance, fine tuneable filtered table

rxjs 5 syntax if needed:

```
const searchString$ = this.searchString.valueChanges
  .startWith('') // start it off
  .debounceTime(300) // debounce the user input
  .distinctUntilChanged(); // only emit when it actually changes

this.nativeBranch$ = Observable.combineLatest(this.bankHttpService.getBankBranches(), 
                                   searchString$)
  .map(([branches, searchString]) => {
    if (searchString) {
      return branches.filter(b => b.name.includes(searchString)); // whatever your filter logic is
    }
    return branches;
  });
```

Comment: uh, you might need to be using rxjs 5 syntax, but it's not very different.  The only difference is in building your stream at the end. everything else is the same

Comment: getting error at code 'filter doesnt exist on type unknown: return branches.filter(b => b.name.includes(searchString)); // whatever your filter logic is
    }

Comment: you need to type your getBankBranches method properly

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are looking for a Filter Table.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

Comment: This will work based on the field passed. like if i hardcode it to search for bank name ,but can i use filters for all the fields?

Comment: this is a very old school approach and not appropriate for the angular context.  Direct DOM manipulation is never advised in angular.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question